# Rolling dice script Python

Tags: python, dice

thanks for read this.

I was trying to "Reset" the script below to every time the user answer "NO" on the rolling dice sentence, the script goes back to the beginning. But, i dont know whats is wrong. The script consist on choose the dice that you want to roll and get a random number. Now, i cant run the script, doesn't work anymore.

```
import random


def d4():
    rolagemD4 = str(random.randint(1, 4))
    retorno = input("resultado do d4: " + rolagemD4 + "\n Gostaria de rolar outro D4, Sim(S) ou Não(N)?")
    if (retorno == "S") or (retorno == "Sim") or (retorno == "sim"):
        rolagemD4 = 0
        d4()
    if (retorno == "N") or (retorno == "Não") or (retorno == "Nao") or (retorno == "nao"):
        principal()

def d6():
    rolagemD6 = str(random.randint(1, 6))
    retorno = input("resultado do d6: " + rolagemD6 + "\n Gostaria de rolar outro D6, Sim(S) ou Não(N)?")
    if (retorno == "S") or (retorno == "Sim") or (retorno == "sim"):
        rolagemD6 = 0
        d6()
    if (retorno == "N") or (retorno == "Não") or (retorno == "Nao") or (retorno == "nao"):
        principal()

def d8():
    rolagemD8 = str(random.randint(1, 8))
    retorno = input("resultado do d8: " + rolagemD8 + "\n Gostaria de rolar outro D8, Sim(S) ou Não(N)?")
    if (retorno == "S") or (retorno == "Sim") or (retorno == "sim"):
        rolagemD8 = 0
        d8()
    if (retorno == "N") or (retorno == "Não") or (retorno == "Nao") or (retorno == "nao"):
        principal()

def d10():
    rolagemD10 = str(random.randint(1, 10))
    retorno = input("resultado do d10: " + rolagemD10 + "\n Gostaria de rolar outro D10, Sim(S) ou Não(N)?")
    if (retorno == "S") or (retorno == "Sim") or (retorno == "sim"):
        rolagemD10 = 0
        d10()
    if (retorno == "N") or (retorno == "Não") or (retorno == "Nao") or (retorno == "nao"):
        principal()

def d12():
    rolagemD12 = str(random.randint(1, 12))
    retorno = input("resultado do d12: " + rolagemD12 + "\n Gostaria de rolar outro D12, Sim(S) ou Não(N)?")
    if (retorno == "S") or (retorno == "Sim") or (retorno == "sim"):
        rolagemD12 = 0
        d12()
    if (retorno == "N") or (retorno == "Não") or (retorno == "Nao") or (retorno == "nao"):
        principal()

def d20():
    rolagemD20 = str(random.randint(1, 20))
    retorno = input("resultado do d20: " + rolagemD20 + "\n Gostaria de rolar outro D20, Sim(S) ou Não(N)?")
    if (retorno == "S") or (retorno == "Sim") or (retorno == "sim"):
        rolagemD20 = 0
        d20()
    if (retorno == "N") or (retorno == "Não") or (retorno == "Nao") or (retorno == "nao"):
        principal()

def d100():
    rolagemD100 = str(random.randint(1, 100))
    retorno = input("resultado do d100: " + rolagemD100 + "\n Gostaria de rolar outro D100, Sim(S) ou Não(N)?")
    if (retorno == "S") or (retorno == "Sim") or (retorno == "sim"):
        rolagemD100 = 0
        d100()
    if (retorno == "N") or (retorno == "Não") or (retorno == "Nao") or (retorno == "nao"):
        principal()

def principal():
    print("Gostaria de jogar dados? : ")
    print("1: dado de 4 faces")
    print("2: dado de 6 faces")
    print("3: dado de 8 faces")
    print("4: dado de 10 faces")
    print("5: dado de 12 faces")
    print("6: dado de 20 faces")
    print("7: dado de 100 faces \n")
    print("8: Não quero jogar dados")

    choice = input()

    principal()

    if choice == "1": d4()
    if choice == "2": d6()
    if choice == "3": d8()
    if choice == "4": d10()
    if choice == "5": d12()
    if choice == "6": d20()
    if choice == "7": d100()
    if choice == "8": exit()
    else :
        print ("Opção Não cadastrada, selecione uma válida \n")
        principal()
```

Comment: Your functions all look similar except for the randint why not just pass that value to 1 function and just change it to a string and insert into retorno

Comment: _Now, i cant run the script, doesn't work anymore_ Saying "it doesn't work" is not much help.  Instead, tell us what the program **actually does**.  Do you get an error?  Does the program run, but you get unexpected results?  Do you get no results at all?

Comment: After you pick a choice you have a principal() so infinite loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def d(face):
    rolagem = str(random.randint(1, face))
    retorno = input("resultado do d"+str(face)+": " + rolagem + "\n Gostaria de rolar outro D"+str(face)+", Sim(S) ou Não(N)?")
    if (retorno == "S") or (retorno == "Sim") or (retorno == "sim"):
        rolagem = 0
        d(face)
    if (retorno == "N") or (retorno == "Não") or (retorno == "Nao") or (retorno == "nao"):
        principal()

def principal():
    print("Gostaria de jogar dados? : ")
    faces=[4,6,8,10,12,20,100]
    for index,value in enumerate(faces):
       print(str(index+1)+": dado de "+str(value)+" faces")
    print("8: Não quero jogar dados"+"\n")

    choice = int(input("Pick one"))
    print(choice)
    
    if 1<= choice <8: 
        d(faces[choice-1])
    else if choice ==8: 
        exit()
    else :
        print ("Opção Não cadastrada, selecione uma válida \n")
        principal()
```

You could rework it to so that all you need is 1 function just pass the face value. principal() after choice made an infinite loop. Made a list for all the faces so you can access them instead